# Stop Windows logging me out and closing all of my apps on sleep

Tags: sleep, windows-11, login, lock-screen, logout

Window 11 is logging out when my computer sleeps due to inactivity. At least I believe that is what's happening, as all of my apps are closed when I unlock the screen. If I intentionally lock my screen it doesn't get logged out.

I would like Windows to lock the screen during inactivity, but I would not like to be logged out.

Everything keeps telling me how to disable the lock screen, which is not what is happening and not what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to fix this?

I'm on a personal computer on a local account.

Comment: As additional info, I can intentionally lock my screen without logging out.

Comment: Have you defined a screen-saver (it will run before the computer enters sleep)?

Comment: I haven't defined a screen saver, but I'm not sure it accomplishes what I would like. I am fine with the screen locking and the computer sleeping, and that is a desired behavior. What I am attempting to avoid is the logout, which terminates all of my running programs. I can try it to see if it affects that behavior, though

Comment: Knowing if you are on a domain would help people answer this.

Comment: Personal computer, local account

Comment: Good question though, definitely should have included that info!

Comment: See if you can find more information : [How to Read Logoff and Sign Out Logs in Event Viewer in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/117980-read-logoff-sign-out-logs-event-viewer-windows.html).